# powerbi Create a line graph of files created overtime

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a line graph or column chart with cumulative files created over time but am struggle.

my table has a list of files with the created dates of those files however i'm struggling to get a graph that shows files created over time.

If i put created date and count of file name it just shows files created on a specific date not the total

[image]

This is a small section of the data and for example this show show that on 24/03/2003 11 files were on the system and then on the 25/03/2003 we had 23 files on the system so on and so on.

does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a running total the basic pattern is:

```
Running Total :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( YourTable[NumberOfFiles] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'YourCalendar'[DateColumn] ),
        'YourCalendar'[DateColumn] <= MAX ( 'YourCalendar'[DateColumn] )
    )
)
```

It will work best if you have a calendar table to fill in missing dates. If you don't have one use the date column in your date, so replace 'YourCalender[DateColumn]' with 'YourTable'[DateColumn]. You may have to chnage the SUM with a COUNT of some other logic.

[image]

Comment: when i do this and i have to use count as there is no column with a the number of files just the list of files, i just get the total number of files in the running total for everyday https://imgur.com/a/JHKicgX

Comment: If I change my example measure to COUNT, and the value column to text I get the same result as my answer. Something is overriding the filter context. 
https://github.com/itconsultantonthedge/PowerBIExampleFiles/blob/master/SO_Question_62176520.pbix